# Create a heap-based 2D array without using double pointer syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax

**I need to declare a 2D array as the member variable of a class.** I can't use STL (so, no vector), and I've been asked to avoid double/triple pointers. I want to be able to reference elements in this 2D array using subscripting notation, e.g. `arr[0][0]`. The array also must be declared on the heap due to its size.

Due to the requirements I have, none of the existing answers on StackOverflow meet my needs.

What I've been trying to do is:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  MyClass() : arr(new int[1000][2]) {}

  // other stuff here

 private:
  int arr[1000][2];
};
```

The error I get after compiling that class is "cannot initialize a parameter of type `int *` with an lvalue of type `int[1000][2]`". Clearly, I can solve this by using pointer syntax, but, as mentioned above, I've been asked to use "array syntax" for code clarity.  **I was hoping someone with a better understanding of C++ could explain how to use "array syntax".**

Comment: Why are you allocating memory with `new` for a fixed size array?

Comment: 1. reimplement `std::vector` yourself, 2. use that.

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<int, 2>>(1000)`

Comment: @cigien: I need to ensure that the array goes on the heap, and I thought that `new` was the way to make that happen.

Comment: @MarekR I can't use STL at all. It's a major requirement

Comment: Then you need pointers. `int arr[1000][2];` is on the stack, and you can't do anything about that.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Maybe there was a miscommunication between me and my manager. It looks like it's not possible to avoid the double pointer syntax while meeting all these other requirements. ‍♀️

Comment: It may be possible, but it depends on the other requirements. Good multidimensional matrix implementations use 1D memory buffer to avoid cache misses and calculate position in that buffer from 2D coordinates passed by user.

Comment: Of course it's possible with only 1 pointer. Easy even. `new int[1000][2]` returns `(int*)[2]`.  Just declare arr as `int (*arr)[2]` and you are good to go. Math is fast on that too.

Comment: @cigien  Turns out it can be done without any pointers in the class definition, let alone multiple pointers, by using a reference. I've added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can do this without double/triple pointers. You can even do this without use of any pointers in the class declaration. But first lets look at the more common approach. A 2D array is a simple extension of a 1D array.

Starting off with the standard way this is done for a 1D array of 1000 ints w/o using `vector`. The pointer, `arr`, is on the stack but points to an array of 1000 ints on the heap.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : arr(new int[1000]) {}

private:
    int *arr;
};
```

Elements are accessed the usual way. For instance `arr[0]=42;`

Extending this to a 2D array in the heap is a simple extension of the above.
You need to declare the member variable as a pointer to a 1D array instead of the basic type.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : arr(new int[1000][2]) {}

private:
    int (*arr)[2];
};
```

Similarly, you can refer to elements of the 2D array the usual way: `arr[0][0]=42;`

Finally, there is the approach that completely eliminates pointers except the one required for the `new`. Here we initialize a reference. The trick is to add a third level to new, the `[1]` so that the `*new` returns an object that is the actual 2D int array. Structurally, it is no different than what the pointer version above does but lets us directly initialize a reference to a 2D int array. It's certainly not a common idiom so I'd stick with the ptr approach.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : arr(*new int[1][1000][2]) {}
    ~MyClass() {delete[] arr;}
//private:  // to test
    int(&arr)[1000][2];
};


int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.arr[2][1] = 42;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your class has an array in it, and you use `new` to create a new instance of that class, that array is on the heap. You can still access the array with `arr[i][j]`.

Why not do something like this?

```cpp
class myClass {
  public:
    int arr[1000][2];
};

int main() {
    myClass* test = new myClass;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            test->arr[i][j] = 5;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 classes to achieve this.

```cpp
class BaseArray {
public:
    int& operator[](int x) { return this->arr[x]; }
    int operator[](int index) const { return this->arr[index]; }

    int arr[2];
};

class myClass {
public:
    myClass() {}
    ~myClass() {}

    BaseArray& operator[](int index) { return this->arr[index]; }
    BaseArray operator[](int index) const { return this->arr[index]; }

    BaseArray arr[1000];
};
```

Optionally use can use templates to make this class more dynamic.

```cpp
template<class TYPE, int arraySize>
class BaseArray {
public:
    TYPE& operator[](int x) { return this->arr[x]; }
    TYPE operator[](int index) const { return this->arr[index]; }

    TYPE arr[arraySize];
};

template<class TYPE, int dim1, int dim2>
class myClass {
public:
    myClass() {}
    ~myClass() {}

    BaseArray<TYPE, dim2>& operator[](int index) { return this->arr[index]; }
    BaseArray<TYPE, dim2> operator[](int index) const { return this->arr[index]; }

    BaseArray<TYPE, dim2> arr[dim1];
};

int main()
{
    myClass<int, 1000, 2> myArray;
}
```

**EDIT**
When you provide the array dimentions `int arr[1000][2];` the variable will automatically be allocated in the stack. If the array needs to be fully dynamic, you can just use a double pointer `int** arr = { nullptr };` and initialize it at the constructor as shown below.

```cpp
class myClass {
public:
    myClass()
    {
        arr = new int* [1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            arr[i] = new int[2];
    }

    ~myClass()
    {
        /* Make sure to delete or else it might flag a memory error. */
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            delete[] arr[i];

        delete[] arr;
    }

    int** arr = { nullptr };
};
```